# html <select> tags doesn't work with boostrap classes in IE 8 angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angularjs app with multiple angular ui-bootstrap tabs one of which is static tab and others dynamic tabs.

html select tag with options works fine in static tab and the layout is designed using bootstrap styling like col-*,form-control,form-group but the same select tag on dynamic tab doesn't work in IE 8 but works well in FF and chrome.I am unable to select any options as the drop down shows and closes immediately after click.

To make the select work across dynamic tabs ,i need to remove all  bootstrap styling.

Can anyone help me with this issue of html select tag with bootstrap 3 styling across dynamic tabs.Please find the plunk for example...but i cannot run this plunker in IE 8.
http://plnkr.co/edit/LiDjvdZDBKjo3sRqkd5w?p=preview

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LiDjvdZDBKjo3sRqkd5w?p=preview can run this example in Chrome but not in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it on IE just not on IE8 because it doesnt support most html5 stuff. I tried your link on IE11 and it worked fine. Its just an IE problem. I know that this should have been a comment but I cant comment yet :(

Comment: Discovered the problem only in IE 8 and work fine in IE 9 and above and chrome and FF.I have discovered that ng-grid version 0.2.7 doesn't work well with latest version of angularjs(1.2.x).The only alternate way is replace ng-grid with normal table as ng-grid stopped support for older versions.